# Java JDBC on SQLite

Tags: java, macos, sqlite, jdbc

I'm using java JDBC to connect to SQLite on my Mac. The official tutorial is using windows. However I'm using a Mac. 
Below is the command I ran in the terminal at `connect` folder. This the command provided in the tutorial. https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-java/sqlite-jdbc-driver/

```
java -classpath ".;sqlite-jdbc-3.27.2.1.jar" net.sqlitetutorial.Connect
```

Below is my file hierarchy.

```
╭─  ~/sqlite ········································at 17:27:22
╰─ tree
.
├── db
│   └── chinook.db
└── java
    └── connect
        ├── net
        │   └── sqlitetutorial
        │       ├── Connect.class
        │       └── Connect.java
        └── sqlite-jdbc-3.27.2.1.jar

5 directories, 4 files
```

Blow is the `Connect.java` the tutorial provided, I only change`String url =` to my own path in my computer.

```
package net.sqlitetutorial;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

/**
 *
 * @author sqlitetutorial.net
 */
public class Connect {
     /**
     * Connect to a sample database
     */
    public static void connect() {
        Connection conn = null;
        try {
            // db parameters
            String url = "jdbc:sqlite:/Users/anasiangangster/sqlite/db/chinook.db";
            // create a connection to the database
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);

            System.out.println("Connection to SQLite has been established.");

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            try {
                if (conn != null) {
                    conn.close();
                }
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        connect();
    }
}
```

The original from the tutorial

```
String url = "jdbc:sqlite:C:/sqlite/db/chinook.db";
```

Anyway, when I ran the command(I provided in front) at `connect` folder.
I get this error message.

```
Error: Could not find or load main class net.sqlitetutorial.Connect
```

Even though, I follow the troubleshooting method the tutorial provided. I'm not be able to solve it. 
Please help me if can. Thank you so much.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093928/what-does-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The classpath separator is the colon (":"), not the semicolon. It's only a semicolon on windows, which is probably why the tutorial uses that. So, just update the classpath param to: `-cp .:sqlite-jdbc-3.27.2.1jar` :)

NB: sidenote, but, sqlite is a weird fit for java. something like [h2](https://www.h2database.com/html/main.html) makes a lot more sense. SQLite gives virtually no benefits: You still need to ship an SQLite engine and launch it from within the process if you want it to feel lightweight, OR you need to explicitly ask the user to install the thing, at which point you might as well ask them to install a full featured DB like postgres. H2 is in-process, does not require you to ship one executable for each and every os/architecture combination you intend to support, and does not require messing about with trying to make the host OS launch native apps. It 'just works'. You should use sqlite only if you have a specific need for precisely sqlite and nothing else will do (for example, you're on android, which provides sqlite for you, or, you're trying to inspect or change firefox data storage, which are sqlite dbs).

Comment: OMG, I literally stuck here for most a week!! Thank you so much Sir. I'm doing this with my school project. None of us in the group is very familiar with android programming, so we decided using Flask in python for our backend server.